# How to modify xdotool output to export them as variables?

Tags: command-line, xdotool

I am executing this command:

`xdotool getmouselocation --shell`

and it gives me:

```
X=1020
Y=563
SCREEN=0
WINDOW=90183822
```

How can I get the X value and the Y value into a variable, for use later on in the script?

Comment: X=1020 and Y=563 already stored in variable and you can use it in your script.  What actually you want?

Comment: How can I use it? It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: e.g. X=10
Y=20
Z=$((X+Y))                 like that

Comment: That doesn't work. I don't think it is saving them as a variable.

Comment: Ok. Just write $ in front of variable value.  Like `b=$(pwd)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll find the answer in the [xdotool man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xdotool.1.html):

> ```
> getmouselocation [--shell]
>        Outputs the x, y, screen, and window id of the mouse cursor.
>        Screen numbers will be nonzero if you have multiple monitors
>        and are not using Xinerama.
>
>        --shell
>            This makes getmouselocation output shell data you can eval. Example:
>
>             % xdotool getmouselocation --shell
>             X=880
>             Y=443
>             SCREEN=0
>             WINDOW=16777250
>
>             % eval $(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)
>             % echo $X,$Y
>             714,324
> ```